# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express - Painting inside panel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I am "having fun" with Visual C++ some time already. And today i decided, i want to draw some colored pixel inside "panel". The goal is - later, when i will learn how to do that - draw pixels inside panel, taking colors from array. But for now, i just want to create few pixel inside panel.

Lets say i got a panel 20x20, and i want put there 3 pixels somewhere not near edge. And let say every pixel gonna be other color. I was reading a bit and found some ideas, but didnt get anything to work.

Do i need to use that to put single pixel? (i am guessing 3,3,3,3 are cords, corners of rectangle).

```
Color aColor = Color::Green;
SolidBrush^ aBrush = gcnew SolidBrush(aColor);
e->Graphics->FillRectangle(Brush, 3, 3, 3, 3);
```

Also, then how to make it draw a pixel into "panel1" WHEN PRESSING A button. Cuz if i put that code directly in panel1, it should draw these pixel right after compiling right? And i want draw pixels after pressing a button.

Don't be too rough for me, i am learning it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a single pixel, draw a 1-by-1 rectangle.

```
e->Graphics->FillRectangle(Brushes::Green, 3, 3, 1, 1);
```

The last two parameters are width and height.

This code needs to be in a `Paint` handler.
It will then draw the pixel at all times.

To only draw the pixel once you click a button, set a flag in your class when you click the button, and put the drawing code in an `if` statement.

You should then call `panel->Invalidate()` to force the panel to repaint so that your drawing appears.

Comment: Well yeah, the thing is i lack even basics, i could use a example code, cuz every tutorial i found on the internet is or putting code exactly inside panel1 (after doubleclick) or some advance stuff i dont even understand. And i would love it to draw it after pressing a button, so the code should be inside button part right?